# mysql single table group by removing zero elements

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a single table as below

```
| ID |        CREATED       |                TITLE           |
| 1  |  07/09/2015 14:02:48 |  Render farm problem           |
| 2  |  06/16/2015 09:34:20 | Render server THSSE12 crashing |
| 3  |  05/16/2015 09:44:38 |  Patch to LG4 switch port 25   |
```

I'd like to be able to count the occurrence of a key word in the TITLE field e.g. Render and format the result by year and month

```
| YEAR | MONTH | COUNT |
|2015  | 5     | 0     |
|2015  | 6     | 1     |
|2015  | 7     | 1     |
```

I have tried several inner joins but without any joy as the months with 0 counts do not show. This is where I'm at:-

```
 SELECT 
    CONCAT(YEAR(c.CREATED),MONTH(c.CREATED)) AS cdate,
    c.CREATED,
    COUNT(c.ID)
FROM 
    HD_TICKET AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        CONCAT(YEAR(t.CREATED),MONTH(t.CREATED)) AS sdate,
        t.CREATED,
        COUNT(t.ID) AS tid
        FROM HD_TICKET t
        WHERE t.TITLE LIKE '%render%'
    ) AS t_count
ON c.CREATED = t_count.CREATED
GROUP BY YEAR(c.CREATED), MONTH(c.CREATED)
```

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm confused by your dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first generates all years/months values and then left join the desired data.  All details inline.  if you prefer, you can use the same trick on years. [fiddle here](http://rextester.com/DSQ46184)

```
select  calendar.year_, calendar.month_, 
        coalesce(mydata.count_,0) as count_                    -- coalesce used to obtain 0 on missing data.
from
(   select y.year_, m.month_
    from
    (select distinct YEAR(CREATED) as year_ FROM hd_ticket) as y      -- all posible years
         ,                                                            -- comma here produces cross join
    (select 1 as month_ union all select 2                            -- all months 
     union all select 3 union all select 4
     union all select 5 union all select 6
     union all select 7 union all select 8
     union all select 9 union all select 10 
     union all select 11 union all select 12) as m
) as calendar                                                  -- a calendar: all years and all months
left join
(
    select count(*) as count_, year(CREATED) as year_, month(CREATED) as month_
    from HD_TICKET
    where TITLE like '%render%'
    group by year(CREATED), month(CREATED) 
) as mydata 
on calendar.year_ = mydata.year_ and calendar.month_ = mydata.month_
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Luis, many thanks for this I have run this on our live data and it produces exactly the required output. Thanks again for your prompt response

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I believe this would provide you with what you need. Use `SUM()` with `CASE` expression to count occurences of a substring.

It uses a little trick which is to check the length of your column, replace occurences of your substring for 0 characters and substract the length of new string from the original one, then round the result and divide it by the length of your substring :)

**Case-sensitive:**

```
select
  year(created) as year,
  month(created) as month,
  SUM(CASE WHEN title like '%render%' THEN round((length(title)-length(replace(title, 'render', '')))/length('render')) ELSE 0 END) AS count
from
  hd_ticket
group by
  year(created), month(created)
```

**Case-insensitive with `lower()`:**

```
select
  year(created) as year,
  month(created) as month,
  SUM(CASE WHEN lower(title) like lower('%reNder%') THEN round((length(title)-length(replace(lower(title), lower('reNder'), '')))/length('reNder')) ELSE 0 END) AS count
from
  hd_ticket
group by
  year(created), month(created);
```

[*Try it online on Rextester*](http://rextester.com/RFGC68014)

Case-insensitive search will provide you with your expected output.

```
| year | month | count |
+------+-------+-------+
|2015  | 5     | 0     |
|2015  | 6     | 1     |
|2015  | 7     | 1     |
```

Comment: Kamil, many thanks for this. When applying this to the live data it gives some unexpected results. I'll try and look into this further to see if I can find the problem. Thanks for your help